# "Sibi quisque nunc nominet eos quibus scit et vinum male credi et sermonem bene"

Tags: grammar-identification

In Seneca's *Moral Letters* (letter 83):

> Sibi quisque nunc nominet eos **quibus scit et vinum male credi et sermonem bene.**

How to parse the bold part grammatically? why are *vinum* and *sermo* in the accusative? (or should I say nominative if this AcI)? In their translation Loeb supplies *potest* but it doesn't solve the issue (So let each one call to mind those who, to his knowledge, can be ill trusted with wine, but well trusted with the spoken word;).

Can we say, as it seems accordingly, *credo sermonem tibi*?  or *credo vinum (?) tibi* ?(rather than credo *sermonem tuum* or credo *tibi (in) sermone* or *credo sermoni tuo*)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Aliquam rem alicui credere* means (besides other things) "to entrust something to someone," particularly with the underlying idea of: "for safekeeping." See [Lewis & Short, II A.](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcredo) Note that Lewis & Short list this even before the arguably more familiar meaning "to believe someone," considering it closer to the word's "original" meaning.

So you can indeed say *credo vinum tibi*, "I entrust you with wine," but if I say *vinum male tibi creditur*, well, it means something like "it's better not to give you wine, if one ever intends to have it back" (i.e., you'll drink it), but *sermo bene tibi creditur* means: "it is safe to tell you something" (i.e., you'll keep it to yourself). Or that's how I would interpret it.

Comment: d_e asked why "vinum" & "sermonem" are in the accusative and conjectured that this is a consequence of indirect speech (accusative-infinitive ["credi"] construction). If so, then why is this indirect speech a part of the subordinate "qui"-clause? Usually, the "qui"-clause is subordinate to the indirect speech with its verb in the subjunctive.

Comment: @tony Well, it is this way around because of what Seneca is trying to say. There is no "qui" clause subordinate to the AcI because there's nothing in the AcI that the author wants to qualify further. And in any event, there's no rule saying relative clauses cannot contain indirect speech; in fact, this is more common than you seem to think. Just take the very first example Allen & Greenough give in their [chapter on relative pronouns](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/relative-pronouns).